# Match product dimensions with regular expression

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, regular-language

I am trying to match length width and height with a regular expression.

I have the following cases

```
Artikelgewicht3,7 Kg
Produktabmessungen60,4 x 46,5 x 42 cm

or

Artikelgewicht3,7 Kg
Produktabmessungen60 x 46 x 42

or

Artikelgewicht3,7 Kg
Produktabmessungen60 x 46
```

The second case can be matched with `(\d+) x (\d+) x (\d+)`, which works fine.

I further tried to match the first and the third case with `(\d+)(\\,\d+)? x (\d+)(\\,\d+)? x (\d+)(\\,\d+)?`.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `\\ ` escapes the backslash and matches the character `\ ` literally. Also your third case has only 2 dimensions while your expression expects 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use optional matches in your regex to cover all 3 cases:

```
(\d+(?:,\d+)?) x (\d+(?:,\d+)?)(?: x (\d+(?:,\d+)?))?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wR7qE5/1)

This will give `length` in 1st capturing group, `width` in 2nd capturing group and `height` in 3rd.

Each group is using this sub-expression:

```
(\d+(?:,\d+)?)
```

Which is 1 or more digits **optionally** followed by a comma and 1+ digits for decimal part.

Also, note that height part is an optional match as we're using `(?: x (\d+(?:,\d+)?))?` to make that part optional.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as:

```
^Produktabmessungen\K(.+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/hD0zR5/1) (and mind the different modifiers!).
You do not really need the `\K` in this situation but will need the multiline flag. What language are you using?