# Parse measurements (multiple dimensions) from a given string in Python 3

Tags: regex, python-3.x, parsing, units-of-measurement, named-entity-recognition

I'm aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161012/parse-python-string-for-units) and [this library](https://pypi.org/project/quantulum3/) but they didn't help me with these specific cases below. How can I parse measurements like below:

I have strings like below;

```
"Square 10 x 3 x 5 mm"
"Round 23/22; 24,9 x 12,2 x 12,3"
"Square 10x2"
"Straight 10x2mm"
```

I'm looking for a Python package or some way to get results like below;

```
>>> a = amazing_parser.parse("Square 10 x 3 x 5 mm")
>>> print(a)
10 x 3 x 5 mm
```

Likewise;

```
>>> a = amazing_parser.parse("Round 23/22; 24,9x12,2")
>>> print(a)
24,9 x 12,2
```

I also tried to use "[named entity recognition](http://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/master/features/models/ner.html)" using "ner_ontonotes_bert_mult" model. But the results were like below:

```
>>> from deeppavlov import configs, build_model
>>> ner_model = build_model(configs.ner.ner_ontonotes_bert_mult, download=True)
>>> print(ner_model(["Round 23/22; 24,9 x 12,2 x 12,3"]))
<class 'list'>: [[['Round', '23', '/', '22', ';', '24', ',', '9', 'x', '12', ',', '2', 'x', '12', ',', '3']], [['O', 'B-CARDINAL', 'O', 'B-CARDINAL', 'O', 'B-CARDINAL', 'O', 'B-CARDINAL', 'O', 'B-CARDINAL', 'O', 'B-CARDINAL', 'O', 'B-CARDINAL', 'O', 'B-CARDINAL']]]
```

I have no idea how to extract those measurements from this list properly.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39452278/10183880) regex:

```
>>>re.findall("(\d+(?:,\d+)?) x (\d+(?:,\d+)?)(?: x (\d+(?:,\d+)?))?", "Straight 10 x 2 mm")
<class 'list'>: [('10', '2', '')]
```

But it does leave an empty value in the resulting list if the input contains 2 dimensions and it doesn't work if there is no whitespace between numbers and "x"s. I'm not good with regex...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the given examples, you might use:

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?:,\d+)? ?x ?\d+(?:,\d+)?(?: ?x ?\d+(?:,\d+)?)*
```

In parts

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `\d+(?:,\d+)?` Match 1+ digits and optionally a `,` and 1+ digits
- `?x ?` Match `x` between optional spaces
- `\d+(?:,\d+)?` Match 1+ digits and optionally a `,` and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `?x ?\d+``Match`x` between optional spaces and 1+ digits
  - `(?:,\d+)?` Optionally match a `,` and 1+ digits
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HVzm1Q/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/SH17eM)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"(?<!\S)\d+(?:,\d+)? ?x ?\d+(?:,\d+)?(?: ?x ?\d+(?:,\d+)?)*"
test_str = ("Square 10 x 3 x 5 mm\n"
    "Round 23/22; 24,9 x 12,2 x 12,3\n"
    "Square 10x2\n"
    "Straight 10x2mm\n"
    "Round 23/22; 24,9x12,2")
result = re.findall(regex, test_str)
print(result)
```

Output

```
['10 x 3 x 5', '24,9 x 12,2 x 12,3', '10x2', '10x2', '24,9x12,2']
```

Comment: This looks very promising. I will try this ASAP

Comment: This is pretty amazing. I still have lots of things to learn about regex. Thank you so much @The fourth bird . I know this is asking too much but, is there way to also discard some special characters and parse strings like this: Square 10/10; Ø24,1 x Ø3 x 5,22 mm

Comment: @MehmedB You could add the character `Ø` before the digit and make it optional using `?` For example https://regex101.com/r/AtRdHm/1 If you want to add more characters you might use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and list the characters that you would allow.

Comment: @igorkf You can make the `[cm]` part optional and make the pattern case insensitive https://regex101.com/r/itBGco/1 Shall we clean up our previous comments a bit?